# ASP.NET Core - IIS and HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I'm developing a website in ASPNET Core and I want to publish it on IIS.
If I set binding with **only HTTP** in IIS (and remove redirect to https from `program.cs`) **it's works**.

But if I'm going to add binding **with HTTPS in IIS it doesn't works**, it's return a 503 error (Service Unavailable).

Have anyone got this error?

I'm installing on Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10.0

*EDIT 1:*
I also tried the same configuration on another PC with Windows 11 and IIS and here works with any problem

Comment: First, check if you do configure the bindings correctly, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and the correct URLs are used to access the site. If you use the wrong URL, the traffic goes to another site or another server and any error (like 503) is expected.

Comment: The binding is correct, I tried the same on a PC with Win11 installed and it's works... It possible it's something connected to TLS protocol?

Comment: You will have to edit your question to make it clear what binding(s) you have configured. "I tried the same on a PC" is rarely helpful, as things won't work automatically from machine to machine. 503 errors are not caused by SSL settings, so even if you run an SSL report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html I don't think it reveals much helpful information.